# When iterating through a list, how do I keep track of a list element to be deleted later on?

Tags: c++

In this example, I build a [linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/list-cpp-stl/) of 4 Person objects, each of which has an *age*. I'd like to iterate through the list of Persons, keep track of the youngest person, and then remove that person from the list.

Here's what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

struct Person
{
    Person(int x): age(x) {}

    int age;
};

int main() {

    // Create 4 Person instances
    Person p1 = Person(50);
    Person p2 = Person(35);
    Person p3 = Person(99);
    Person p4 = Person(17);

    // Build a list of persons
    std::list<Person> persons = {p1, p2, p3, p4};

    // Delete the list-element of the youngest person
    int minAge = 999;            // track the lowest age so far
    Person* youngin = nullptr;  // track the person with the lowest age so far

    // Iterate through each person in the list, looking for someone with a lower age than all previous
    for(auto const &p : persons){
        if(p.age < minAge){
            std::cout << "Found someone younger. Age: " << p.age << std::endl;

            // Update minAge and youngin
            minAge = p.age;
            // youngin = ???;
        }
    }

    // Delete the youngest person from the list
    // persons.erase(youngin);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I 1) retain a pointer (I think?) to the youngest person "so far" and 2) remove that element from the list at the end?

---

## UPDATE

It seems I've oversimplified my minimal reproducible example. @NathanOliver appears to have the best solution for what I asked, so I'll choose his as the accepted but if anyone is willing to help me further,

Suppose that there is a 5th person not in the list,

```
Person p5 = Person(30);
```

Now, how do I identify which of the 4 people in the list is closest in age to `p5`, and then remove that person from the list? (In this case `p2` should be identified and removed.)  I don't see how to apply Nathan's solution using `std::min_element` to this situation.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the standard algorithms and a lambda to have this done for you.  [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) can be used to find the minimum element and the iterator it returns can be passed to the lists `erase` member function to have it removed from the list.  That would look like

```
persons.erase(std::min_element(persons.begin(), 
                               persons.end(), 
                               [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs){ return lhs.age < rhs.age; }));
```

If you need to use the minimum before you dispose of it yo can split up the call like

```
auto min_it = std::min_element(persons.begin(), 
                               persons.end(), 
                               [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs){ return lhs.age < rhs.age; }));
//use min_it here
person.erase(min_it); // get rid of the minimum
```

---

Update:

You can still use `min_element` to find the element, we just need to find the minimum difference instead of the minimum element.  We just need to change the lambda to to compare the differences of the ages and the value to find instead of the just the ages.

```
Person p5 = Person(30);
persons.erase(std::min_element(persons.begin(), 
                               persons.end(), 
                               [&](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs){ 
                                   return std::abs(lhs.age - p5.age) < std::abs(rhs.age - p5.age);
                               }));
```

I used `[&]` in the lambda so it capture `p5` by reference so we can compute the difference.  You can see it working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec6d5d956960c681).

Comment: In case the OP is interested, [See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/decf31f7f729c6bb).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I oversimplified my example (sorry!!). Suppose instead that there's a 5th person, p5, not in the list. How do I identify the person closest in age to p5 and remove that person from the list?

Comment: @Ben I've updated the answer with a way to solve the update.

Comment: @Ben They are very handy.  [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is a good reference and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXeu4fj3zOs) is a decent talk on them.

Comment: Your original answer itself was great, but the fact you've kept updating with more information and helping the OP further is just fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

The type of `p` is a `std::list<Person>::iterator` (As it needs to be a "node" class, in most cases storing a pointer to the next node and the value of the node).

`std::list::erase` takes an iterator, whereas that for loop dereferences the iterator, so you don't get the iterator.

So, you need to use `std::list::begin` and `std::list::end` to get iterators.

```
typename std::list<Person>::iterator youngin;  // track the person with the lowest age so far
// Or:
decltype(persons.cbegin()) youngin;

// Iterate through each person in the list, looking for someone with a lower age than all previous
for (auto it = persons.cbegin(); it != persons.cend(); ++it){
    if (p->age < minAge) {
        std::cout << "Found someone younger. Age: " << p.age << std::endl;

        // Update minAge and youngin
        minAge = p->age;
        youngin = it;
    }
}

// Delete the youngest person from the list
persons.erase(youngin);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use pointer, this code should do :

```
int main() {
    // Build a list of persons
    std::list<Person> persons = {Person(50), Person(35), Person(99), Person(17)};

    Person yongestPerson = persons[0];

    // looking for someone with a lower age than all previous yongestPerson
    for(persons p : persons){
        if(p.age < yongestPerson.age){
            std::cout << "Found someone younger. Age: " << p.age << std::endl;

            // Update minAge and youngin
            yongestPerson = p
        }
    }

    // Delete the youngest person from the list
    persons.remove(yongestPerson);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Person` needs an `operator==` for this to work.  The OP doesn't have one at present.